# Java Cascading Enums?

Tags: java, enums

In my project, I have such class :

```
class Statut {
    String satDomain;
    String staCode;
}
```

But working with Strings is not what I want. It is too permisive and using constants is not enough.

I wanted to use enums but find a problem :

```
class Statut {
    Domain satDomain;
    StatutCode staCode;
}
enum Domain { }
enum StatutCode { }
```

This solution is far better, but you can set a StatutCode that is not in the selected Domain.

Did you find a solution in your project to such problem ?

Thank for your help

Fluminis

Comment: So, to clarify: each value for Domain has a discrete set of StatutCode values associated with it? And they differ from one Domain to another?

Comment: Yes that's it. But now on, working with Strings is completely messy and I try to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually slight improvement on extraneon's answer.

Define `StatutCode` enum first, and then assign EnumSet< StatutCode > to each `Domain` enum value.  Then the validation is pretty simple in `Statut` constructor

```
enum StatutCode
{
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR
};

enum Domain
{
  DOMAIN_1( EnumSet.of( StatutCode.ONE, StatutCode.TWO ) ),
  ...
  DOMAIN_N( EnumSet.of( StatutCode.TWO, StatutCode.THREE ) );

  private final EnumSet< StatutCode> validStatCodes;

  Domain( EnumSet< StatutCode > validStatCodes )
  {
    this.validStatCodes = validStatCodes;
  }

  public boolean isValidCode ( final StatutCode code )
  {
    return validStatCodes.contains( code );
  }
}

class Statut {
    final Domain staDomain;
    final StatutCode staCode;

    Statut(
      final Domain staDomain,
      final StatutCode staCode
    )
    {
      if ( ! staDomain.isValidCode( staCode ) )
      {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Invalid code " + staCode + " for domain " + staDomain
          );
      }

      this.staDomain = staDomain;
      this.staCode = staCode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest making your fields `private` and `final` and adding a constructor the verifies that the constructed object is well-formed.

Comment: Why not but it is not possible in the context of the project.

In fact, I have a service that call the DB to get the full Statut objects defined like that :
List<Statut> findStatus(String domain, List<String> staCodes);

or like that in the second exemple
List<Statut> findStatus(Domain domain, List<StatutCode> staCodes);

And I call the method this way :
findStatus(MyConst.DOMAIN_1, Arrays.asList(MyConst.STA_CODE_1, MyConst.STA_CODE_2))
I want the constants itself are linked to the domain...

Comment: @flumins There appear to be architectural issues with the way you are handling your database.

Comment: You're right, the model is a little messy but I think such case can appears in other project as well, isn't it ?

Comment: @flumins I don't mean the "domain model", but the difficult to change decisions made about interfacing with the database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually find that a problem. I tend to use a unmodifiable validation Map<Domain,StatutCode>()` if run-time validation is sufficient, or the contents is pulled from a database.

You could add such a validator on Statut. Make the only setter like `setDomainAndStatutCode(Domain domain, StatutCode statutCode)` and check whether the input is valid.

Otherwise I'd use an `enum DomainAndStatutCode`. Lot's of work and maintenance of course, so really not a nice solution. Might be good if the dataset is limited and correctness is a must.

Comment: +1. The only suggestion, since `Domain` will be an enum, use `EnumMap` ( not `HashMap`) for validation map.  It's much more efficient.